# Cleaner way to increment last IPv4 digit

Tags: ruby

Here is my IP: `192.168.2.0`

I need to get an array like this one:

```
["192.168.2.0",
 "192.168.2.1",
 "192.168.2.2",
 "192.168.2.3",
 "192.168.2.4",
 "192.168.2.5"]
```

Here is how i increment last digit up to `5`:

```
ip = '192.168.2.0'

ips = 0.upto(5).map do |n|
  ip.sub(/\.\d+$/, '.' << n.to_s)
end
```

However it is dog slow and i hate how it looks.

**Important** - i need initial `ip` to stay untouched so i can later refer to it via `ip` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Standard lib has [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-succ), which supports a `succ` method.

```
require 'ipaddr'
ip = "192.168.2.0"

ips = [ip]
5.times do 
  ips << IPAddr.new(ips.last).succ.to_s
end
p ips
# =>["192.168.2.0", "192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.2", "192.168.2.3", "192.168.2.4", "192.168.2.5"]

#Ranges work:
ip_range = IPAddr.new("192.168.2.0")..IPAddr.new("192.168.2.5")
p ip_range.map(&:to_s)
# =>["192.168.2.0", "192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.2", "192.168.2.3", "192.168.2.4", "192.168.2.5"]
```

Comment: Neat! Thank you much. SO Rocks. New day - new lesson learned :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you deal with digits under `9` you can use `succ`(or `next`):

```
ip = '192.168.2.0'

p (0...5).inject([ip]) { |l| l << l.last.succ }

#=> ["192.168.2.0", "192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.2", "192.168.2.3", "192.168.2.4", "192.168.2.5"]
```

If you'll need to increment to say up to `255`, use `split` which is much faster than regex:

```
p (0..255).inject([ip]) { |l, d| l << (l.last.split('.')[0..2] << d).join('.') }

#=> ["192.168.2.0" ... "192.168.2.255"]
```

#### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=cleaner-way-to-increment-last-ipv4-digit.rb&run=true)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it uses split/join instead of regexes.

```
ip = '192.168.2.0'

ips = 0.upto(5).map do |n|
  ip.split('.').tap{|i| i[-1] = n }.join('.')
end
```

Comment: `i[-1] = n` is an (I think) cleaner alternative to `i.pop; i << n`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) from stdlib as it will gracefully handle the octet rollover (when you hit .255) and also has some useful features for subnetting and such.

```
require 'ipaddr'
current = ip = IPAddr.new('192.168.2.0')
array = [ip]
until current.to_s == '192.168.2.5'
  array << current = current.succ
end
array.map!(&:to_s)
```